# Robots.txt - how to set a rule to not index pages with parameters

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

We recently added a new section to our webpage.  Essentially it's a shopping product catalog that allows for filtering of different attributes - helping the visitor whittle down the results to what it is they need.

The parameters are passed into a URL and I know Google will index these pages as different pages although they essentially hold the same content.  I know I can specify which pages Google (and other search engines) can index by setting up the appropriate rules in the Robots.txt file.

This is on the of the pages in question: http://www.reyniersaudio.com/recording-computer-studio-gear/audio-interfaces
As you'll see, if you select any of the filters on the right side of the page or select a "Sort By" option it will send you to a new page which has the same url + a string that starts with "&filters=" and "&order_by="

For example: [http://www.reyniersaudio.com/recording-computer-studio-gear/audio-interfaces/&filters=Form+Factor%3A%3A1U+Full+Rack&order_by=part_price::asc](http://www.reyniersaudio.com/recording-computer-studio-gear/audio-interfaces/&filters=Form+Factor%3a:1U+Full+Rack&order_by=part_price%3a%3aasc)

What rule should I add to my robots.txt that will tell the search engines not to index those redundant pages?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1235687) has a way for you to tell them directly what/how to interpret your various parameters.  No need to use robots.txt

Comment: That works fine for Googlebot. But you can't do that for every search engine or random bot. Using robots.txt is a more reliable way to prevent bots in general from crawling pages that you don't want indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent Googlebot from crawling URLs that contain "&", you can write:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*&
```

Or, if you don't want any bot to do it, just replace `Googlebot` in that with `*`.

Note that not all bots handle wildcards. Googlebot and MSN bot (whatever it's called these days) do. I think Blekko's bot does. I know that mine does, as well. Some might not, as wildcards aren't part of the original robots.txt specification (which never was a "real" standard).